# Python Scrapy not going through all the tags

Tags: python, html, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

I am Trying to write a ebay script that goes through each product in a page and goes to the next page and does the same

but for some reason the script is going to each next page but not through each items on a page i think i have written the selectors right

a **ul** contains all the **li** elements that represent each items on a page

But the problem is scrapy only goes through the first link in the page and skips the rest of the page and goes to the next page

for each page scrapy only takes only one item, where it should take all the item one by one

i have used **xpath** selector `.//ul[@id="ListViewInner"]/li`
the **ul** with the id `ListViewInner` and every **li** under it

i have used css selector `.sresult.lvresult.clearfix.li.shic` class that each li has but in every case

stops after taking only 1 item from a page
[image: here]
 i am printing ***i am here*** for every item section *(where scrapy should enter)* but exiting only after the first element not going through rest of the 49 items in the page

here is the simple code

```
class EbayspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ebayspider"
    #allowed_domains = ["ebay.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.ebay.com/sch/hfinney/m.html?item=132127244893&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2562']


    def parse(self, response):

        DEF_SELECTOR = './/*[@id="ListViewInner"]/li'

        for attr in response.xpath(DEF_SELECTOR):

            #item = EbayItem()
            #linkse = 'a.vip ::attr(href)'
            #link = attr.css(linkse).extract_first()
            #yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.url, link), callback=self.parse_link, meta={'item': item})"""

            print '\n\n\tI AM HERE!!'
        #next_page = '.gspr.next ::attr(href)'
        #next_page = response.css(next_page).extract_first()
        #if next_page:
            #yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.url, next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

i have commented the execution part cause the program is not even gong through 50 products in each page

here is the inspect element from the page

[image: here]
and enlarged
[image: here]

**what am i doing wrong here ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guess: set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False` in settings.py

Your log shows that scrapy is downloading robots.txt and if it obeys its contents it will definitely not crawl any further.

Besides that I don't see a reason why your parse function shouldn't extract multiple items / links.

When I ran this in `scrapy shell` (without ROBOTSTXT_OBEY):

```
for attr in response.xpath('//*[@id="ListViewInner"]/li'):
    print attr.css('a.vip ::attr(href)').extract()
```

(which is 100% based on your code) ... I got a long list of URLs:

```
[u'http://www.ebay.com/itm/Cat-Caterpillar-Excavator-Monitor-320B-320BL-320BLN-321B-322BL-325BL-151-9385-/361916086833?hash=item5443e13a31:g:NMwAAOSwX~dWomWJ']
[u'http://www.ebay.com/itm/257954A1-New-Case-580SL-580SM-580SL-Series-2-Backhoe-Loader-Hydraulic-Pump-/361345120303?hash=item5421d8f82f:g:KQEAAOSwBLlVVP0X']
#.....
```

...which is what you expect.

Another problem I see in your code is the way how you create the request URLs by joining response.url with link while link will hold a complete link already. It's better to use Scrapy's linkextractors here as they handle such situations out of the box.

PS: please post your logs in text format, makes searching and diffing easier.